# How do I use a pre-made app with my project?

Tags: python, django, macos

sorry I'm a total noob but I can't find anywhere that actually explains this. I want to make a web blog, and I figured instead of rolling my own I would use a pre-made one, and I picked the blog from the basic apps project (https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps). I installed everything fine, added the apps to my settings file, synced the DB's, etc. But now I don't know what to do. How to I actually use the blog? When I run the test server it says I have to do manage.py startapp but I already have the app folder. What should I do? Again, sorry for the noob question.

Best,

Jake

Comment: do you have the README file?

Comment: Have you also installed any dependencies required by that blog app?

Comment: Did you try running `python manage.py runserver` and then went into your browser `http://localhost:8000` and see?

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies. I did, and when I went to the server it gave me the "You haven't done anything yet, run the command add appname" thing.

The read me file is here: https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: I put the basic folder that contains all the apps in the site-packages folder in the Python version folder that I'm using

Comment: do I have to add anything to the main urls file?

Comment: try add (r'^blog/', include('basic.blog.urls')) to your urls then goto /blog/

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is: if app's documentary doesn't explain how to install (use, etc.) app, then its better to forget about using that app.

How can you rely on 5-month-not-updated-not-tested-not-well-documented app? There should be better solution.